# WPF Datagrid -hide RowDetails

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Is there any way to hide the **row detail** of a WPF **DataGrid**? I want to show only the row in the data grid.

[image]
Thanks

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=oExtrationMasterList}" RowHeaderWidth="0" x:Name="DataGridMaster" AreRowDetailsFrozen="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,128,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="199" Width="614" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionChanged="DataGridMaster_SelectionChanged" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="30"  Binding="{Binding TransactionDate}" Visibility="Hidden" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Transaction Date" Width="*" Binding="{Binding TransactionDate}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Transaction Count" Width="*" Binding="{Binding TransactionCount}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: if I google your question the first hit gives the answer.. :)

Comment: after the google search I came across RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed" , RowHeaderWidth="0", AreRowDetailsFrozen="True" but non of them work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"` on your datagrid.

EDIT-

```
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                    
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Comment: I have tried this. But when i click on the row it shows the details as system.data.datarowview

Comment: @RV1982 - RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed" is setting my detail row collapsed. but the arrow on before the first column of the row will expand it with ystem.data.dataRowView.. how do i remove that?

Comment: Sample you post seems to work fine for me though. But you can override the `RowDeatilsTemplate`. Check the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. your answer took out the message system.data.dataRowView. it still shows the arrow which can be expand. I think i can live with that :). Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the `RowDetailsVisibilityMode` property to `Collapsed`.

```
RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
```

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailsvisibilitymode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) this "Gets or **sets** a value that indicates when the details sections of rows are displayed".

In XAML you can set is like bellow:

```
<sdk:DataGrid RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"/>
```

In C#, you can use this:

```
myDataGrid.RowDetailsVisibilityMode = DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode.Collapsed;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`DataGrid.RowDetailsVisibilityMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailsvisibilitymode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property.

> Gets or sets a value that indicates when the details sections of rows
>   are displayed.

[`DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrowdetailsvisibilitymode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) enumeration has;

```
Member name           Description
Collapsed             The row details section is not displayed for any rows.
Visible               The row details section is displayed for all rows.
VisibleWhenSelected   The row details section is displayed only for selected rows.
```